# Regex in SoapUi's "Contains" assertion causes the assertion to always fail?

Tags: soapui

I am using SoapUi 5.5.0 to create functional tests for my REST webservice. My project can already make REST requests and display the JSON response. Now I need to make an assertion about this response. But I can't get my assertion to work the way I want to.

For the sake of example, lets say that I want to assert that the JSON response contains either the string "args" or "brgs". If the JSON contains either/both of these strings, the assertion will pass; otherwise the assertion will fail. To accomplish this, I open my "REST Request" test step and add a new "Contains" assertion. I configure the assertion to check whether the JSON response contains a match to the regex "[ab]rgs".

After executing the REST Request, I can see that the JSON response contains (among other things) the string `"args": {},`. I expected my regex "Contains" assertion to pass at this point. But the assertion still says it failed. The assertion always fails. I cannot get a single regex "Contains" assertion to pass. Am I fundamentally misunderstanding how SoapUi works? or is the program bugging out?

For your reference, here is the JSON response of the REST endpoint I'm testing against:

```
{
   "args": {},
   "headers":    {
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate",
      "Host": "httpbin.org",
      "User-Agent": "Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)"
   },
   "origin": "199.82.243.104, 199.82.243.104",
   "url": "https://httpbin.org/get"
}
```

Here is a picture of the configuration of my "Contains" assertion:
[image: assertion configuration]

Here is my entire SoapUi project file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<con:soapui-project id="ee46fa47-c454-437d-82a3-1b61154f78ea" activeEnvironment="Default" name="REST Project 1" resourceRoot="" soapui-version="5.5.0" abortOnError="false" runType="SEQUENTIAL" xmlns:con="http://eviware.com/soapui/config">
    <con:settings/>
    <con:interface xsi:type="con:RestService" id="a6af7b2e-3c2a-4419-8524-141b5cbe02b5" wadlVersion="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02" name="https://httpbin.org" type="rest" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <con:settings/>
        <con:definitionCache type="TEXT" rootPart=""/>
        <con:endpoints>
            <con:endpoint>https://httpbin.org</con:endpoint>
        </con:endpoints>
        <con:resource name="Get" path="/get" id="29a38000-2a32-420a-b33e-f978cc1bd088">
            <con:settings/>
            <con:parameters/>
            <con:method name="Get 1" id="8d40ae42-98f1-4bcb-8247-7fdfad1415d6" method="GET">
                <con:settings/>
                <con:parameters/>
                <con:representation type="RESPONSE">
                    <con:mediaType>application/json</con:mediaType>
                    <con:status>200</con:status>
                    <con:params/>
                    <con:element xmlns:get="https://httpbin.org/get">get:Response</con:element>
                </con:representation>
                <con:request name="Request 1" id="f5c85bda-524b-4d2f-baf7-635f88774a17" mediaType="application/json">
                    <con:settings>
                        <con:setting id="com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlRequest@request-headers">&lt;xml-fragment/></con:setting>
                    </con:settings>
                    <con:endpoint>https://httpbin.org</con:endpoint>
                    <con:request/>
                    <con:originalUri>https://httpbin.org/get</con:originalUri>
                    <con:credentials>
                        <con:authType>No Authorization</con:authType>
                    </con:credentials>
                    <con:jmsConfig JMSDeliveryMode="PERSISTENT"/>
                    <con:jmsPropertyConfig/>
                    <con:parameters/>
                </con:request>
            </con:method>
        </con:resource>
    </con:interface>
    <con:testSuite id="6cd7e9db-fb93-4f99-a47c-f0b9a0450e16" name="TestSuite 1">
        <con:settings/>
        <con:runType>SEQUENTIAL</con:runType>
        <con:testCase id="3b79550c-f88b-455e-9c26-008971a68641" failOnError="true" failTestCaseOnErrors="true" keepSession="false" maxResults="0" name="TestCase 1" searchProperties="true">
            <con:settings/>
            <con:testStep type="restrequest" name="REST Request" id="2ada1bc8-3541-4918-a937-d83de9b2e395">
                <con:settings/>
                <con:config service="https://httpbin.org" methodName="Get 1" resourcePath="/get" xsi:type="con:RestRequestStep" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                    <con:restRequest name="REST Request" id="d17f2536-e9a3-4ddb-ad93-08db2e4a5551" mediaType="application/json">
                        <con:settings>
                            <con:setting id="com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlRequest@request-headers">&lt;xml-fragment/></con:setting>
                        </con:settings>
                        <con:encoding>UTF-8</con:encoding>
                        <con:endpoint>https://httpbin.org</con:endpoint>
                        <con:request/>
                        <con:originalUri>https://httpbin.org/get</con:originalUri>
                        <con:assertion type="Simple Contains" id="8e6831f2-a067-4dc5-9ba7-163a73dd003b" name="Contains">
                            <con:configuration><token>[ab]rgs</token><ignoreCase>false</ignoreCase><useRegEx>true</useRegEx></con:configuration>
                        </con:assertion>
                        <con:credentials>
                            <con:authType>No Authorization</con:authType>
                        </con:credentials>
                        <con:jmsConfig JMSDeliveryMode="PERSISTENT"/>
                        <con:jmsPropertyConfig/>
                        <con:parameters/>
                    </con:restRequest>
                </con:config>
            </con:testStep>
            <con:properties/>
        </con:testCase>
        <con:properties/>
    </con:testSuite>
    <con:properties/>
    <con:wssContainer/>
    <con:oAuth2ProfileContainer/>
    <con:oAuth1ProfileContainer/>
</con:soapui-project>
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstood how SoapUI handles regular expressions in the Contains assertion.

Your regular expression `[ab]rgs` is expecting that the **entire body** will consist of only that text. Which is probably not what you want.

If you want your expression to be **anywhere in the body**, it needs to be: `.*[ab]rgs.*`, where `.*` of course represents any text.

[reference](https://www.soapui.org/docs/functional-testing/validating-messages/getting-started-with-assertions.html#3-1-The-Contains-Assertion)